# How can I visualize network architectures effectively?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, visualization, code-visualization

Is there some sort of software that can do so? Specifically, I would like to visualize Resnet18. Is there no other way other than to just draw it myself? Here is an example of what I want to see:

### Sample Architecture Visualization

[image: Sample Architecture Visualization]

Comment: Here is one option https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-deep-learning-neural-network-model-keras/

Comment: Doesn't look like what you attached but `Tensorboard` looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhc3g.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one : http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html . It lets you visualize neural networks by letting you modify several parameters and finally lets you export the architectures as SVG files. You can also choose between 3 visualization styles, namely FCNN, LeNet & AlexNet.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!